# How to remove a string between two words without removing those words?

Tags: python, regex

I want to remove a substring between two words from a string with Python without removing the words that delimit this substring.

what I have as input : "abcde"
what I want as output : "abde"

The code I have:

```py
import re

s = "abcde"
a = re.sub(r'b.*?d', "", s)
```

what I get as Output : "ae"

------------Edit :

another example to explain the case :

what I have as input : "c:/user/home/56_image.jpg"
what I want as output : "c:/user/home/image.jpg"

The code I have:

```py
import re

s = "c:/user/home/56_image.jpg"
a = re.sub(r'/.*?image', "", s)
```

what I get as Output : "c:/user/home.jpg"

/!\ the number before "image" is changing so I could not use replace() function I want to use something generic

Comment: Use lookbehind for `b`and lookahead for `d`(not sure how to do that in python ...)

Comment: Like so: `r'(?<=b).*?(?=d)`

Comment: Your title is a bit confusing because you are not really dealing with words. According to your actual example, you just want to remove a letter and could just as easily do: `s.replace('c', '')`

Comment: Temrikoo it was just an example, I will adjust it, thanks for your answer, that's was the expression that I'am looking for

Comment: In added example, you can do `s.replace('56_', '')` too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like bellow:

```
''.join('abcde'.split('c'))
```

Comment: Which is basically a fancy way of saying `s.replace('c', '')`

Answer (score 0):

I would phrase the regex replacement as:

```py
s = "abcde"
a = re.sub(r'b\w*d', "bd", s)
print(a)  # abde
```

I am using `\w*` to match zero or more word characters in between `b` and `d`.  This is to ensure that we don't accidentally match across words.

Answer (score 0):

You are also matching what you want to keep with an empty string, that is why you don't see it in the replacement.

You can use capture groups and use the group in the replacement, or lookarounds which are non consuming.

For example, using group 1 using `\1` in the replacement:

```
(b)\w*?(?=d)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PG3d9j/1)

Or using a lookaround, and use an empty string in the replacement.

```
\d+_(?=image)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RWG3Pv/1)